# how to divide the malloc memory to blocks in c

Tags: c, memory-pool

if I have *p=malloc(1000),I want to divide the memory p into blocks of 200 and 300, and get the address of the blocks and use it. Is there any simple way to do this?

Comment: Yes; just add 200 bytes to your pointer.  That's your memory; you can do whatever you want with it.

Comment: That only makes sense to do iff you will always want to free them again at the same time, in whch case that is a valid optimization. If you want to build your own allocator, you would normally go to the low-level platform methods for memory blocks...

Comment: This is, potentially, a very bad idea. You should at least take into consideration any alignment issues.

Comment: Good point, as using the first 47 of 247 bytes as `char`s and then the remaining 200 as `int`s would be devastating to performance.

Answer (score 5):

Is there a reason you're not doing...

`char* firstblock = malloc(200);
char* secondblock = malloc(300);
char* thirdblock = malloc(500);`

If you wanted to take the approach you are though, you could do

`char* wholething = malloc(1000);
char* firstblock = wholething;
char* secondblock = wholething + 200;
char* thirdblock = wholething + (200 + 300);`

but it doesn't make as much sense to me.

The first reason I'd recommend using separate blocks is because you could free a block when you're done with it. If you are freeing all of them at the same time anyway then it's true it could slightly improve performance in the regard of fewer function calls, but that benefit is negligible. The second reason is that your system may be happier with a few smaller blocks than one big one because a big block doesn't fit in a page as well. Although the opposite could be said since fewer blocks have to be kept track of. Again, though, the performance benefit or impact is so slight in most cases that it really just doesn't matter which approach you take. So the third reason, readability, is why I say to use individual blocks.

---

Just keep in mind that the offsets may or may not need to be multiplied by sizes.

In this case, yes...

`char* wholething = malloc(1000 * sizeof(int));
int* firstblock = wholething;
int* secondblock = wholething + 200;
int* thirdblock = wholething + (200 + 300);`

But in this case, no...

`int* wholething = malloc(1000 * sizeof(int));
int* firstblock = wholething;
int* secondblock = wholething + 200;
int* thirdblock = wholething + (200 + 300);`

Answer (score 1):

`malloc` is sure to give you a contiguous block. You can loop through the block like you'd through an array. Dividing into blocks is simply indexing into the correct location.

```
char *p;
p = malloc(sizeof(char)*10+sizeof(int)*20);
char *x = p;
int *y = p+10;
```

Now `x[0]` to `x[9]` can be used for `char`s and `y[0]` to `y[19]` can be used for `int`s

This is a very stupid way. A better way is simply to use separate blocks.

Comment: anyone using `sizeof(char)` does not understand what he writes. How oten do you ask: "How many elephants are one elephant?"

Comment: I use `sizeof(char)` for readability. I **know** that `sizeof(char)` is sure to be 1 byte (though not necessarily 8 bits). I find my code more readable when I use `sizeof(char)`. It's not a huge waste of my time

Comment: Another approach that I find useful in conveying understanding is `char *x; int *y; char *p = malloc(sizeof(*x)*10 + sizeof(*y)*20); x = p; y = (int*) (p + 10);`.  Use `sizeof(*pointer_variable)`.

Comment: That's what I always do. Also, I never make such mixed type blocks unless it's absolutely necessary (even in that case, it's better to wrap it all up in a struct)